# Primes, congruent, Fermat squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I need some proof or procedure to solve the question:

For given n = 1 or > 1, We know by fermat, $p = x^2 + ny^2$ for an odd prime $p$. Now, can we proof the

(a) $(-n/p) = 1$ and $(p/q) = 1$ for every odd prime $q\mid n$?

(b) $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ for $n \equiv 0, 1 \pmod{4}$?

(c) $p \equiv 1 \pmod{8}$ for $8\mid n$?

The proofs of the above problem will answer many questions easily, especially primes of the form $p = x^2 + ny^2$. So, kindly discuss the proofs.

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181257/primes-of-the-form-a2qb2) is possibly related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you explain the notation $(-n/p)$?

By the way, is this homework?

Concerning $(b)$ and $(c)$, take a look at the groups $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, square each element, and see which values are possible. You'll see that if you also use the fact that $p$ is odd, the results $(b)$ and $(c)$ follow easily.

I leave it to you as an exercise on purpose, its really useful to find this out for yourself, but let me know if you need more hints!

**Edit:**

$(b)$: First of all, $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ has 
\begin{align*}
0^2=2^2 = 0\\
1^2=3^2=1
\end{align*}
So an even square is zero, an odd square is one.

Two cases. If $n \equiv 0 $ (mod 4), then $ny^2 \equiv 0 $ (mod 4) and in particular $ny^2$ is even. Since $p$ is odd, $x^2$ (and hence $x$ itself) must be odd. Then $x^2 \equiv 1$. Hence
\begin{align*}
p &= x^2 + ny^2\\
&\equiv 1 + 0\\
&\equiv 1
\end{align*}

If $n \equiv 1$ (mod 4), then $p \equiv x^2 + y^2$. The sum of two odd numbers or two even numbers is even, since $p$ is odd we know either $x$ is odd and $y$ is even or the other way around. In any case we find by the inspection of squares in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ above that $p \equiv 1 + 0 \equiv 1$ as desired.

Notice that strictly speaking i was working modulo 2 most of the time in the last argument. Formally i could have argued that $n \equiv 1$ (mod 4) implies $n \equiv 1$ (mod 2) and hence $p \equiv x^2 + y^2$ (mod 2), from which the statement of the parity of $x$ and $y$ follows. Then, we return to working modulo 4 again: the value of a number modulo 2 is of course not enough to determine its value modulo 4, but as we saw above, we are able to find the value of the *square* of the number modulo 4, just by knowing its value modulo 2. Since we are only interested in the values of the squares, this suffices.

Now $(c)$. We determine the squares in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$. Noticing that $5 \equiv -3$ hence $5^2 \equiv 3^2$ and similarly $7^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \equiv 1^2$, we can quickly see that all odd numbers square to one (In fact this shows that $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}^*$ is the Klein four group). Now $8 | n$ is a reformulation of $n \equiv 0$ (mod 8), which certainly implies $ny^2$ is even, and again since $p$ is odd we know $x^2$ and hence $x$ must be odd. Putting this together we see
\begin{align*}
p &= x^2 + ny^2\\
&\equiv 1 + 0\\
&\equiv 1
\end{align*}

Modulo 8 of course, as desired. Whereever i left out the (mod ...) notation i assume it to be clear modulo which number we work.

Hope this clears it up.

Comment: JOACHIM! here (x, y) =1. Before that, if you can prove for (n, p) =1 and (x, y) =1, p divides $x^2$+n$y^2$  then (-n/p) = 1. Of course we are talking about quadratic reciprocity. Still, I need complete help in the above problem.

Comment: JOACHIM! Still I need more explanation or hints or complete proof of the above post. Kindly explain.

Comment: I'll get back to it soon, its bedtime in my time zone.. In the meantime, could you confirm that its not a homework question?

Comment: JOACHIM! It is not homework question.

Comment: JOACHIM! more than my expectation there in your solution. It is simple and superb. Thanks a lot. What is your real name and where you are working?

Comment: @vidyaojal Sorry it took a while, take a look at my profile and the link supplied there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your notation $(-n/p)$ means the Legendre symbol, you can use the following argument to prove the first of your result (a):

If $p = x^2+ny^2$ then $0 \equiv x^2+ny^2 \pmod{p}$, so that $-ny^2 \equiv x^2 \pmod{p}$, which shows that $-n$ must be a quadratic residue of $p$.
(Note that we can multiply both sides by $y^{-2}$, since clearly $y$ is invertible $\pmod{p}$.)

To complete the proof of (a), suppose that $q$ is a prime dividing $n$, so that $n \equiv 0 \pmod{q}$. Then $p-x^2 \equiv ny^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{q}$, and so $p \equiv x^2 \pmod{q}$, which means that $p$ must be a quadratic residue of $q$, in other words $(p/q) = 1$.

The other parts can be completed using the hints provided above by Joachim.

Comment: OLD John! is not impressed.

Comment: @vidyaojal I am not sure I understand what you mean by that cryptic comment. If there is something mathematically wrong with what I posted, perhaps you could explain?